# Expected Cassandra MapReduce Performance

Tags: mapreduce, cassandra

Having a very specific access pattern for my data, I wonder about the expected mapreduce performance of Cassandra. These are my requirements:

- There will be 10 Million Documents (e.g. JSON, a couple of KB each)
  in my database There will be occasional updates of the documents
- Users want to create results from the whole dataset that require
  processing of each document
- Users will want to do this in a
  semi-interactive fashion, trying out effects of changes they make to
  the processing of each document. Waiting for the result a couple of
  minutes is ok.
- Users would like to be able to spend money (scaling up
  or out) to increase interactive speed if there is a desire to
  increase processing speed.
- There will not be large user numbers,
  processing needs to be done a couple of times per hour, maybe.
- Durability is not a primary concern, as the data is replicated from a
  source system anyway.

This sounds like a good Job for Cassandra and MapReduce but given that MapReduce is not intended to be used semi-interactively but rather as a background job, I wonder what performance possibilities I can expect using Cassandra.

My other options are plain MySQL with documents stored as CLOBS or partitioned Redis.

Can anyone provide clues on how to estimate the speed possibilities?

Comment: Are there other factors than the ones you've listed that make you think this is a good fit for Cassandra?  This sounds like a better fit for Hadoop and MR if you had terabytes or petabytes of data, but it's only about 20GB of data, which can fit on one machine, in RAM even.